# Vim doesn't respect the initial tab distance of a paragraph

Tags: formatting, line-breaks

I have lines of text like these (each of one are single lines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh7Uc.png

Since those text lines have a lot of words vim distribute the whole single line in several sublines(I don't know a better word). As you can see the first subline is tabbed, how can I make vim respect the tab distance of the first subline in the other sublines? of course a fix may be to break the whole text manually between lines, but that's not a solution for me.

This is what I would like to accomplish, I just did it creating line breaks manually but I want vim to do it automatically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmJDO.png

I guess there is something I can add in the vimrc file to achieve what I want but I don't know what.

PD: Just to be sure, I call subline to the lines vim generates automatically when a single line is long enough, thus generating, at least visually, a paragraph.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you integrate the text (or another example) in your question?

Comment: @Biggybi I just edited the question to clarify my issue.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! [if you could add the actual text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/) (in a blockquote or code block), that would help. (In this case, the images may be useful to show the behavior you mean, but having the text could also be helpful.) See also `:help wrap`, etc.

Comment: In fact, `showbreak` may be the right idea here, but it won’t be perfect

Answer (score 1):

`set breakindent` did the magic.